# Add multiple Instagram feeds to theme from username or user ID

Tags: php, instagram, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I need to be able to let users put in either their Instagram username or user ID into a custom field. I need the feed to export just the recent images, and I found a plugin that works well for the most part. I am using Instagram Feed by Smash Balloon, and I have found that I can use the following code in my theme to display a feed the way I need to:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[instagram-feed id='username']"); ?>
```

I need to be able to replace the `username` with the User Id that a user can insert into the Advanced Custom Field text field I have created. I know I can echo that code with this:

```
<?php the_field('instagram_field'); ?>
```

How can I take what is echoed from my `the_field` parameter and insert it into the `username` space in my shortcode?

If there is a better way to allow for multiple feeds to be added into Custom Post Types I am open to it, but this solved all other issues I had with styling, needing multiple feeds, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is close to correct.

The issue is with declaring the field, the answer provided uses the_field and not get_field. Which should be used for storing variables.

```
$custom_acf_field = get_field('instagram_field');
echo do_shortcode("[instagram-feed id='$custom_acf_field']");
```

This should work out ok if not you may wish to declare the shortcode seperately:

```
$custom_acf_field = get_field('instagram_field');
$insta_code = [instagram-feed id='$custom_acf_field'];
echo do_shortcode($insta_code);
```

Comment: glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a variable to your advanced custom field for it to be echoed within the Instagram Shortcode username attribute.

```html
$custom_acf_field = the_field('instagram_field');


echo do_shortcode("[instagram-feed id=$custom_acf_field]");
```

To then allow multiple feeds/Shortcodes you could wrap the above in a foreach loop with some arguments relevant to each user.

Comment: I gave that a shot but it seems like the shortcode isn't accepting a variable within it, the plugin doesn't load correctly with it in there (but it works if I paste the code that it should be accepting in directly). I'm thinking that maybe this isn't possible the way I'm trying to do it?

Comment: Maybe give this a go:   echo do_shortcode('[instagram-feed id="'.the_field('instagram_field').'"]');

Comment: That still keeps them split, it echos out the User ID in text above the plugin, and the plugin just loads with the default user I'm logged in as.

Comment: Maybe if I inserted it into the plugin files somewhere? I'm thinking in the shortcode attributes section?
    
`$atts = shortcode_atts( array( idfield' => isset($options[ the_field('instagram_field'); ]) ? $options[ $custom_acf_field ] : '',`

but that brakes wp, and trying to pass it a parameter like stated above gives me the same results as when I tried that in the theme.

Comment: The plugin support states there is a shortcode support for multiple instagram feeds already - "Yep. You can display multiple Instagram feeds by using our built-in shortcode options, for example: [instagram-feed id="12986477" cols=3]." Have a look at the plugin documentation to see if you can use whats already there by passing the ID via custom field like in the example above